# Dependency injection vs Exporting instance of a class

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm in the process of learning how to structure more complex apps with typescript and how to be a better web-dev in general.

Recently I've been writing the following project: https://github.com/ludersGabriel/toDo/tree/dev/backend. It is a simple app to register toDos.

My question revolves around the backend side of things, which is a graphQL Api. Currently I've got a component structure and each component is separated in a dto, repo and resolver files and I'm not sure how to operate with dependency injection or if I should use it. Right now what I do is something like this:

in the repo file I put every function that deals directly  with the db, heres an example:

```
import { prisma } from '@src/context'
import { Task, TaskCreateInput, TaskUpdateInput } from './task.dto'

class TaskRepo {
  private readonly prisma = prisma

  async createTask (
    data: TaskCreateInput,
    userId: string,
    projectId: string
  ): Promise<Task> {
    return this.prisma.task.create({
      data: {
        ...data,
        user: { connect: { id: userId } },
        project: { connect: { id: projectId } }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

In the resolver file I treat user inputs and call the functions through the repo:

```
import { Task, TaskCreateInput, TaskUpdateInput } from './task.dto'
import { Arg, Authorized, Ctx, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from 'type-graphql'
import { Context } from '@src/context'
import { taskRepo } from './task.repo'
import { OwnerError } from '@utils/auth'

@Resolver(Task)
export class TaskResolver {
  private readonly taskRepo = taskRepo

  private readonly checkOwnership = async (taskId: string, ctx: Context) => {
    const task = await this.taskRepo.task(taskId)
    if (task && task.userId !== ctx.user.id) {
      throw OwnerError()
    }
  }

  @Authorized()
  @Mutation(() => Task)
  async createTask (
    @Arg('data') data: TaskCreateInput,
    @Arg('projectId') projectId: string,
    @Ctx() ctx: Context
  ): Promise<Task> {
    const userId = ctx.user.id

    return this.taskRepo.createTask(
      data,
      userId,
      projectId
    )
  }
```

In order to make this work, what I do now is instantiate the repo class and export that instance, which I then use in every resolver that needs it as a private readonly variable.

What I want to know is if there's any performance difference between doing this, using the same instance for every resolver, and using something like typeDI to work with dependency injection instead.

Also, should I have another file for services between the repos and the resolvers?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps your question will be reopened if you focus it on performance aspect or some other more or less measurable aspect (edit the title as well)

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't recommend DI, I don't have much of a taste for it.  I don't think there will be much of a performance difference but the problem is that once you introduce something like that on a project then you're tightly coupling everything and making everything dependent on it.

Learn about atomic design, modularity (especially in terms of composition / inheritance (and why you should prefer composition)) and the "S" in SOLID principles (since you have so many questions on the design of your project).

A long time ago I liked using DI but as I grew as a dev and fell in love with composition, atomic design and modularity, I've been on a mission to remove anything that's global or anything that introduces coupling between things from my projects.  Which in return has resulted in me being able to build new projects extremely fast because of my focus being on building reusable pieces of code that isn't dependent on anything that I can just quickly slap together into bigger things.

But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Have you got any recommendations on literature for learning about atomic design? I kinda got interested in it.

Also, what I'm doing isn't modularizing everything? Like, how would you go about creating a system that connects to a db to create some entity or to do any other work with that entity if not with a repo?

Comment: DI is sort of the opposite of modularity, modularity is building it bottom up, first the atoms, then the molecules, then upwards, inheritance / DI and those concepts are top down concepts primarily.  But so far your code looks good, I'd just suggest that you don't have god classes doing a bunch of things for other things.  A db I'd break down bottom up, first create the connection/driver, then the adapter, then the models acting on the adapter, each still completely independent.  No "god" class managing everything.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the insights, really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome.  By the way when you look up atomic design and just see "frontend" stuff, just remind yourself that the concept is not only applicable to frontend, use the same concept for everything.